# Regular expression required for password policy generation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to validate a string with following validations:

- 6 to 20 characters long
- One lower-case character
- One upper-case character
- One special character
- One numeric character
- 3 or  greater than 3 consecutive letters not allowed
- 3 or greater than 3  consecutive numerics not allowed

I have created a expression

```
var regex=/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20}$/;
```

which satisfies only following validations:

- 6 to 20 characters long
- One lower-case character
- One upper-case character
- One numeric character

Need Help to create expression for following 3 validations:

- One special character
- 3 or  greater than 3 consecutive letters not allowed
- 3 or greater than 3  consecutive numerics not allowed

Comment: This is more a word of advice, but just for your information, having to jump through all these hoops to make a password and limiting your end users' options only serves to worsen user experience - the only limiting factor of password security against brute force programs is password length, **not** password complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*([a-zA-Z0-9])\1\1).{6,20}$
```

You can add a `lookahead` for the same.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/15

Comment: Because it's not useful? Because there's no principle being shown? Because it's just random regexp-mongering for hire? Because there are dozens of password validation regexp questions which all boil down to the same thing? Because regexps aren't the best way to do password validation? Because we don't want to be complicit in this kind of password rule insanity?